# Capturing video with opencv using Pinovke in c#

Tags: c#, c++, opencv, video

I am coding an WindowsForm application in C# using openCV. I want to capture video from the webcam and show it in a window and i want to do it using P/Invoke,i got c++ code but i don't how can i do it in c#.

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
using namespace cv;
int main(int, char**)
{
VideoCapture cap(0); // open the default camera
if(!cap.isOpened())  // check if we succeeded
    return -1;

Mat edges;
namedWindow("edges",1);
for(;;)
{
    Mat frame;
    cap >> frame; // get a new frame from camera
    cvtColor(frame, edges, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    GaussianBlur(edges, edges, Size(7,7), 1.5, 1.5);
    Canny(edges, edges, 0, 30, 3);
    imshow("edges", edges);
    if(waitKey(30) >= 0) break;
}
// the camera will be deinitialized automatically in VideoCapture destructor
return 0;
}
```

i found a link in github which will detect face from image [Face Detect](https://gist.github.com/zrxq/1115520)

exactly same way i want capture the video from webcam.any reference link will be helpfull.?

Answer (score 0):

```
#region cameracapture
   if (comboBox1.Text == "Capture From Camera")
   {
     try
     {
       _capture = null;
       _capture = new Capture(0);
       _capture.SetCaptureProperty(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CAP_PROP.CV_CAP_PROP_FPS, 30);
       _capture.SetCaptureProperty(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CAP_PROP.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 240);
       _capture.SetCaptureProperty(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CAP_PROP.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 320);
       Time_Label.Text = "Time: ";
       Codec_lbl.Text = "Codec: ";
       Frame_lbl.Text = "Frame: ";
       webcam_frm_cnt = 0;
       cam = 1;
       Video_seek.Value = 0;
       Application.Idle += ProcessFrame;
       button1.Text = "Stop";
       comboBox1.Enabled = false;
     }
     catch (NullReferenceException excpt)
     {
        MessageBox.Show(excpt.Message);
     }
   }
#endregion cameracapture
```

Source: [Codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/722569/Video-Capture-using-OpenCV-with-Csharp)

Comment: i don't  want to use Emgucv i want to get it through Opencv